# output redirection in the function system() seems not to work

Tags: c++, io

I have been scratching my head around this problem for a while, and I couldn't find any answer through surfing the web either.

The problem is that I call `system("csvtojson someFile.csv 1> someOtherFile.json")` inside my program to produce a JSON file. After this line I want to open, read, and process the JSON file. Although, I can see that the file is created, but `fopen()` returns `NULL`.
I read that `system()` is synchronized so I think the rest of my program will not get executed until the `system` call is finished, and so the file will be created.

I suspect the problem is somehow related to redirecting the output stream using "1>"; not sure, though.

Any help or hint will be much appreciated.

Thanks! :)

P.S. I don't want to use a library to convert csv to JSON, and I can't perform the conversion outside the program because there are tons of very large csv files and the only way for me is to convert each to a JSON file inside the program, run my algorithm, and move to the next csv file ( converting it to JSON and saving it in the very same JSON file). So in total I have only one JSON file, being like a buffer for my csv files. Having said that, if anyone has a better design approach that can be implemented quickly, that would be also great.

**UPDATE :** Actual code that exhibits the problem, copied from the OP's answer:

```
int main(){
system("csvtojson Test_Trace.csv 1> ~/Traces/Test_Trace.json");

FILE* traceFile = fopen("~/Traces/Test_Trace.json", "r");
if(traceFile == NULL)
  perror("Error in Openning the trace file");
else
  cout << "Successfull openning of the trace file!" << endl;

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You say that you can see that the file is created (how?), but `fopen()` returns `NULL`. Does it set `errno`?  Set `errno` to 0 before calling `fopen()`, then look at its value after the call if `fopen()` fails (or use `perror` or `strerror` to get a readable error message).

Comment: @KeithThompson You don't need to clear `errno`.

Comment: @EJP: Maybe, but it couldn't hurt. The C standard doesn't require `fopen` to set `errno` on failure, but POSIX does.

Comment: @KeithThompson, the file is created because I can see it on the directory, open it, and it works fine there. I used `perror`, and the message is: `No such file or directory`.

Comment: So the file exists after your program finishes, right? Can you update the question to show some more of your code, including at least everything from the `system()` call to the `fopen()` call? Also, try changing `1>` to `>` (which should do the same thing but is more idiomatic); if that doesn't help, you can remove that paragraph from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your answers. I had to be more detailed in my question as the problem seemed to be somewhere that wasn't clear from my question.

I figured out what was the problem, and would like to share it here (not a super interesting finding, but worth mentioning).

I wrote a simple program to find the problem:

```
int main(){
system("csvtojson Test_Trace.csv 1> ~/Traces/Test_Trace.json");

FILE* traceFile = fopen("~/Traces/Test_Trace.json", "r");
if(traceFile == NULL)
  perror("Error in Openning the trace file");
else
  cout << "Successfull openning of the trace file!" << endl;

 return 0;
}
```

If you run this program you will get the error message `No such file or directory`, but if you replace the address string with the absolute location, i.e., `/home/USER_ID/Traces/Test_Trace.json`, in both `system(...)` and `fopen(...)` calls, your code will work fine. Interestingly, myself suspected that this could be the problem and I changed just the one for `system(...)` but still it wasn't working (though the file was being created in the location that was passed to `fopen(...)`).

EDIT: Thanks to @Peter's comment, this problem was because system() call takes care of `~`, but fopen() does not and need an absolute path. So there is really no need to have both functions been given the absolute path.

Anyhow,

Thanks Again. :)

Comment: `~` expanding to your home directory is something done by your chosen shell or command interpreter, which `system()` typically launches to host and execute the supplied command.   `fopen()` doesn't do that expansion - it relies on calling code to do it.   That is often done by writing code that obtains the value of the environment variable `HOME` (e.g. using `getenv()`) and add that to the string in place of the `~` character before calling `fopen()`.    Redirection like `1>` is also a function of your command shell.

Comment: That's why we should show all relevant parts of code at first, posting your call to `fopen()` would have give you a quick, in-ten-minutes answer, from the community.

Comment: `fopen()` doesn't need an *absolute* path; a relative path works just fine. It just doesn't do the expansions done by the shell, such as `~`, `$VAR` etc. BTW, including your actual code in the question would have saved us all a great deal of time.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the reason for this is because the system command hasn't finished executing by the time your program continues to the next instructions where it tries to read from the file that hasn't been created yet.

Although, this isn't the best way, putting in a short pause might make the difference, or at least let you know if that is the issue.